# Why are notification area icons' settings not saved in Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, taskbar, icons, notification-area

Every time I logon I set several icons to be hidden in taskbar properties. But after reboot this setting is lost. How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you change the taskbar settings, have you first unlocked the task bar? If not the settings will not be remembered.

Don't forget to re-lock.